# Need to tar files old or newer than 48 hrs

Tags: tar

I need to tar -cvf but only tar the files that are added or changed within 48 hrs in our mail directory

How could I do that. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Perhaps the [`find`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) command could be useful?

Comment: Do you've the command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this

```
find MYMAILDIR -ctime 2 | xargs tar -cvf OUTPUT.tar
```

If your filenames have spaces in them, then use `-print0` in `find` and `-0` in `xargs`.

Comment: So I will run this, Out of mail directory or inside of the mail directory and if I run inside mail directory, WIll it file all files that are added 48hrs prior . Basically anything inside of mail directory is what I need to tar.

Comment: I tried with your command its actually backing up everything I tried with this find mail -mtime 2 | xargs tar -cvf OUTPUT.tar, It ran but it says tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors